# Google Form layout will not reset after removing background image

Tags: html, css

Google Form Theme will not reset to newer version after removing custom header image in Theme settings

[image: Desired neat theme with rounded corners]

[image: Old unwanted theme]

What can I do to apply the new theme again? I think this is a bug.

I have a Google Form embedded via iframe.
I set a custom header image in Google Forms theme settings.
When I removed that header from the theme settings, the theme of the Form inside my iframe is (old Google Form iframe theme) the same as if there were still a custom header image. (Instead of the newer neater theme with rounded edges.)

My embedding code may not be relevant as I deem the issue lies Google side:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/<googleformid>/viewform?" width="700" height="6300" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scroll="none">Loading...</iframe>
</div>
```